# Laravel Eloquent `with` select nested relation columns to a flat collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Now say we have an `item` table and a `unit` table, I want to do a selection as below:

```sql
SELECT items.name, units.code 
FROM items JOIN units ON items.unit_id = units.id ;
```

Which is equivalent to below in Laravel query builder:

```php
DB::table('items')
    ->join('units', 'items.unit_id', '=', 'units.id')
    ->select('items.name', 'units.code')
    ->get();
```

Which will return **a flat collection** without any nested columns:

```sh
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4075
     all: [
       {#4074
         +"name": "Galaxy S20",
         +"code": "31",
       },
       {#4036
         +"name": "iPhone 11",
         +"code": "31",
       },
     ],
   }
```

When we try to use Eloquent to query the relational columns, such as:

```php
Item::with('unit:id,code')->get(['name','unit_id']);
```

Which looks really succinct and beautiful, while this returns a nested collection:

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4141
     all: [
       App\Models\Item {#4313
         name: "Galaxy S20",
         unit_id: "6",
         unit: App\Models\Unit {#4289
           id: "6",
           code: "31",
         },
       },
       App\Models\MItem {#4314
         name: "iPhone 11",
         unit_id: "6",
         unit: App\Models\Unit {#4289
           id: "6",
           code: "31",
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Essentially the Eloquent `with` works differently in terms of SQL query:

```sh
>>> DB::getQueryLog();
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select [name], [unit_id] from [items] where [items].[deleted_at] is null",
       "bindings" => [],
       "time" => 10.46,
     ],
     [
       "query" => "select [id], [code] from [units] where [units].[id] in (6)",    
       "bindings" => [],
       "time" => 7.86,
     ],
   ]
```

My question is, is there any way to return a flat collection as the query builder did? Or select the column from the relational table in the `get()` method such as `get([table.column])`?

---

As pointed out by @GTCrais, **it is possible to use the same `join` and `select` methods on a model**.

At least for myself, the main reason to choose `with` or other Eloquent methods is that the succinct syntax. Instead of writing multiple `join...`, you define relations in the models and retrieve data by `with`. If there is not any way to achieve a "flat select" on relation fields by using `with`, this question can be closed.

Comment: You can still use a `join` with eloquent. You can also do `with('relationship:column')` to get only a column

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for your comment. `with('relationship:column')`requires at least `id` + other columns, otherwise will return null.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I believe it is not possible to use `with` to select in a flattened way. As you can see the queries are quite different, `with` does not execute a `join` under the hood.

**As pointed out by @GTCrais and @apokryfos, the simple solution should be just use `select` and `join` on your eloquent model!**

Another sidenote is that, the `flatten` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten) for collections, e.g. `...get()->flatten()` cannot deal with nested relation selected by `with`.

I think the reason is that this `App\Models\Item` object is not a collection at all so `flatten()` will not work on it (Pls correct me if I am wrong).

```sh
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4141
     all: [
       App\Models\Item {#4313
         name: "Galaxy S20",
         unit_id: "6",
         unit: App\Models\Unit {#4289
           id: "6",
           code: "31",
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Again, since I like to stick with using `with` instead of writing `join` and `select`. As a compromise solution to tackle this problem, I convert the collection into an array first, then try to flatten the array.

My final goal is to export those data into a CSV file, so it does not change much by working with the array directly. If you need to keep the collection data type, this might not be a solution for you.

```php
function flatten(array $arr, String $prefix = '')
{
    $flattened = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $flattened = array_merge($flattened, flatten($value,  "{$prefix}{$key}."));
        } else {
            $flattened[$prefix . $key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $flattened;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using `with`, but you can do the same thing you did with `DB`:

```
Item::select('items.name', 'units.code')
    ->join('units', 'items.unit_id', '=', 'units.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Good to know it is possible to do the same thing as DB. My main concern is the succinct syntax by using `with`, in my project I have dozens of columns and multiple relation tables, it is a pain to write `select` and `join` one by one.. So it is not possible to do the flat selection by using `with` right?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no, it's not possible to get the result you want directly. Since `->get()` will return a Collection, you could possibly use one of the Collection methods on the resultset to get what you want - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your info. Yes, I have tried the `flatten` method on the collection and somehow it still returned the same nested collection (also tried changing the nested level). Not sure about the reason, I think it might be because that it only works for a collection object, and this part `App\Models\Item {#4313 id: '1',  ...}` is NOT a collection at all (Item object defined by myself), so the flatten method will not work on it. 
Now I convert the collection to an array first and flatten the array with a flatten function, will update the solution later.

Comment: You could make a macro that does what you want - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#extending-collections